# Setting img.src in React causes application-wide slowdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, html5-canvas

I'm creating a React.JS application that draws images rapidly onto a canvas using the below code.

```
function rapidFrameDrawing(){
       const ctx = this.frame_canvas.current.getContext("2d");
       
       setInterval(async () => {
           console.time("Perf1");
           var base_64_image_data = this.video.getScreenshot();
  
           var image = new Image();

          image.onload = async () => {
             ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
          }

          image.src = base_64_image_data;

           console.timeEnd("Perf1");
      }, 300);
 }
```

The HTML returned by the React component looks like this:

```
render(){
return <div>
    <canvas
      ref={this.frame_canvas}
      width={720}
      height={560}
    />
</div>
}
```

It is fairly straightforward, and the console timer only reports it taking about 10ms or so. The application runs super fast when `image.src = base_64_image_data;` is commented out, but when it is included it causes the whole React application to wait for it to wait for the frame to be displayed.

Why is this and how do I get around it?

Comment: How often is `rapidFrameDrawing`,called  it should only be called once or you must cancel the interval. Also if `this.video` is a HTMLVideoElement it seam like a lot needless processing, encoding and decoding the image when you can just render the video directly to the canvas. `setInterval(() => { ctx.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0) }, 300)`, better yet use timeout and ensure you complete the last capture before attempting the next. ` const capture = () => { ctx.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0); setTimeout(capture, 300) }; setTimeout(capture, 300)}`

Comment: Thank you. rapidFrameDrawing is only called once. While it is a little heavier to decode and draw like this, surely that can't be the issue for such a slowdown? It lasts over 4 seconds. The actual drawing etc less less than 10ms.

Comment: As its stands 4 seconds is a long time however without more information I can think of plenty of situations that it could take that long. You say it runs fine when you remove the line `image.src = base_64_image_data;` I assume that the call to `this.video.getScreenshot` is still being called and not effecting the performance. To me that would be the most likely source of problems, especial if its is seeking frames. And "...less than 10ms", 10ms, 5ms, or even 2ms  Is a long time to render an image, The image is not like huge is it?

Comment: I bump this question highly! I don't even use the canvas - I go straightforward with FileReader and `setImageSource(reader.result as string)`. The files are like 5-10MB and while mapping like 10+ of them (list with little image preview) performance gets demolished. Withj <imn src={undefined} /> and the whole FileReader logic everything is fine and fast. But the moment I use the `imageSource` as src it's over.